# Codeigniter - unable to load multiple views in controller

Tags: codeigniter

Hi everyone thank you for taking time to look at my question.

I have tried to run view (site_nav, site_header and site_footer) together only and it  worked fine.

When I tried to run view (view_home) and the models it also worked fine.

However when I run all the views and models together, the view (site_nav, site_header and site_footer) does not work.

Could anyone please help?

```
public function home(){
    $this->load->model("model_cms_home");
    $data["results"] = $this->model_cms_home->getData("cms_home");
    $this->load->view("site_nav");
    $this->load->view("site_header");
    $this->load->view("view_home", $data);
    $this->load->view("site_footer");
}


VIEW("view_home")



<div id="home_hat1"> <img src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>pics/home_hat1.jpg"> </div>


<div id="content">

    <div id="dinner">

   <div class="home_title">

     <?php
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT `title` , `text1` FROM `cms_home` WHERE       `ID` =1");

    if ($query->num_rows() > 0){
    $row = $query->row_array();

        echo $row['title'];

    }           
    ?>
  </div>

<div class="home_content">

    <?php
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT `title` , `text1` FROM `cms_home` WHERE `ID` =1");

    if ($query->num_rows() > 0){
    $row = $query->row_array();

        echo $row['text1'];

    }           
    ?>
</div>

</div>
```

Comment: What doesn't work exactly?  Do you get a blank page?  Is your page not rendered correctly?

Comment: I get view("view_home") only with the correct data passed into it. But I don't get my header, nav or footer view loaded.

Comment: btw thanks for replying I really appreciate it! =)

Comment: That's weird.  Can you post your `view_home` view in your question?  I suspect something is wrong in it.

Comment: Is that a query you are doing in a view ? please put the view code properly .. its all garbled

Comment: You shouldn't have queries in your view files. They should be in functions in the model, called from the controller, and the data passed to the views as an array.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot call multiple view in one controller function.
This can be done into view.
I suggest you that you should first create a templete and in that template call your views like this

**`templete.php`**

```
<html>
<head>
<body>
   $this->load->view("site_nav");
   $this->load->view("site_header");
   <?php echo $content; ?>
   $this->load->view("site_footer");
</body>
</head>
</html>
```

Comment: You can call view inside another view/template. But it does not mean you cannot call view inside controller.Please learn more [CI3](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/views.html?#loading-multiple-views) [CI2](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/views.html)

Answer (score 1):

MY suggestion is to call other page in `view_home` using `include();`. You cant see other pages as the last page will be called according to your code. If you put an alert in each page you will know it has actually called all the pages.

Comment: Ahhh sorry guys it is a silly mistake.

I have made a comment to myself at the bottom of the view_home page and hence it didnt work.
I have remove the comment and it is working fine now.

Thanks Maxime for pointing out where the problem could be and everyone who tried to help. I really appreciate it! =)

Comment: No problem. Although, you should really implement what @Jeemusu suggested. (No queries in your view, only in a model that is called by your controller.)