# issue with passing variable from controller to view in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

**This is my Code Of Controller**

```
    $datacc['user_id'] = $this->user_id;
    $this->load->view("Templates/header",$this->data);
    $this->load->view("Tax/Tax_Search",$datacc);
    $this->load->view("Tax/Tax",$datacc);
```

in this, i want to pass "$datacc" to my both view files (**Tax.php And Tax_Search**)
but $datacc can't pass to **Tax_Search.php** file

can anyone help?

Thank You

Comment: fetch using <?php echo $user_id; ?> in view file.

Comment: yup m doing the same thing still its not working !

Comment: try to print value of echo $this->user_id; exit; before "$datacc['user_id'] = $this->user_id;" code in controller. and check $this->user_id return value or not.

Comment: if i print "echo $this->user_id; exit;" before "$datacc['user_id'] = $this->user_id;"   it prints Current UserId which i want in view

Comment: try this `$this->load->view("Tax/Tax",array("datacc"=>$datacc));`

Comment: Everything is fine.I think you getting error some where.Try to remove this `$this->load->view("Templates/header",$this->data);` view.

Comment: @ShaifulIslam From his question it shows that he can access the data in Tax/Tax view so no point its stopping over your commented code

Comment: @RKinfotech If i am not wrong you can access it in one view right ?

Comment: @Zeeshan yup i can access it in my one view but can not able to access it in another view

Comment: One view means Tax & not Tax_search right ?
Now try shuffling your line of codes this way and tell me in which view you can access now
$this->load->view("Tax/Tax",$datacc);
$this->load->view("Tax/Tax_Search",$datacc);

Answer (score -1):

You cannot call multiple view in one controller function. 
This can be done in view file.

I suggest you that you should first create a template file and in that template call your views like this

```
template.php
   $this->load->view("Tax/Tax");
   $this->load->view("Tax/Tax_search");
   <?php echo $content; ?>
   $this->load->view("Tax/footer");
```

Let me know if you have queries

Comment: Are you sure you cannot call multiple view?

Comment: Yes damn sure...Because tell me which view will be loaded from there ?

Comment: Why not test yourself.It will load all the views.How you became damm sure.Test yourself.

Comment: chk this out buddy
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13853127/codeigniter-unable-to-load-multiple-views-in-controller
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17401686/codeigniter-multiple-views-in-one-view

If insufficient kindly refer codeigniter documentation for proper way to load multiple views

Comment: Man why don't you test yourself calling multiple view inside controller.The link you provided top answer wrote wrong `You cannot call multiple view in one controller function.` You can call multiple view inside controller and inside view even inside model. There is no rule for proper way to call.You need to write your way.

Comment: For your clarification please learn more about view [here](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/views.html?#loading-multiple-views)